# How we can convert CCD or CDA report to hl7 message through OpenEmr or is there anyother way possible to convert these documents to hl7 message?

Tags: hl7, ccd, cda

How we can convert CCD or CDA report to hl7 message through OpenEmr or is there any other way possible to convert these documents to hl7 message?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a CDA to hl7 message you can use XSLT, as CDA are xml documents, and hl7 v2 messages can be also xml. If once you get the hl7 xml message you want to convert it to | style, sure you can use some tool designed for that propose.

Also remember that if you want to send a HL7 CDA document inside an HL7 message you can use an MDM message.

Hope useful.
Martí